# Styling the 'root' in MUI v5

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

For example I am trying to style [`ListItem`](https://mui.com/api/list-item/)

I can find a lot of example using the `sx` (all use Box as example )
but when I try something like below, it does not work

```
<ListItem button onClick={handleClick}
  sx={{
    root: {
      //
    }
  }}
>
```

Thank you.

**Update**

This attempt also does not work

classes reference:https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L29

```
const MyListItem = styled(ListItem)({
  root: {
    width: "10%",
  },
  button: {
    "&:hover": {
      textDecoration: "none",
      backgroundColor: "blue",
      "@media (hover: none)": {
        backgroundColor: "transparent",
      },
    },
  },
});
```

```
  <MyListItem button onClick={handleClick}>
       //content
      </MyListItem>
```

Comment: try classes instead of sx

Comment: You should use `ListItemButton` instead of passing the prop `button` to `ListItem` in v5 because that prop is deprecated. See how they style the `ListItemButton` [here](https://mui.com/components/lists/#customization).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is how you style the root component using `sx` prop

```
<ListItem
  sx={{
    // your root styles
    "&": {
      // your root styles but with higher CSS specificity
    },
    "&.MuiListItem-root": {
      // your root styles but with even higher CSS specificity
    }
  }}
/>
```

It's similar to the older method in v4:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    // your root styles
    "&": {
      // your root styles but with higher CSS specificity
    },
    "&.MuiListItem-root": {
      // your root styles but with even higher CSS specificity
    }
  }
});
```

```
<ListItem className={classes.root}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]